# How can I display timedelta in hours:min:sec?

Tags: python, csv, timedelta

I am exporting a list of timedeltas to csv and the days really messes up the format. I tried this:

```
 while time_list[count] > datetime.timedelta(days = 1):
        time_list[count] = (time_list[count] - datetime.timedelta(days =  1)) + datetime.timedelta(hours = 24)
```

But it's instantly converted back into days and creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the `str()` conversion of a `timedelta` will always include the `days` portion. Internally, the value is always normalised as a number of days, seconds and microseconds, there is no point in trying to 'convert' days to hours because no separate hour component is tracked.

If you want to format a `timedelta()` object differently, you can easily do so manually:

```
def format_timedelta(td):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds + td.days * 86400, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

This ignores any microseconds portion, but that is trivially added:

```
return '{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:06d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds, td.microseconds)
```

Demo:

```
>>> format_timedelta(timedelta(days=2, hours=10, minutes=20, seconds=3))
'58:20:03'
>>> format_timedelta(timedelta(hours=10, minutes=20, seconds=3))
'10:20:03'
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the answer I was looking for

Comment: Quick follow up, I am sorting the new list of timedeltas and the sort function seems to only look at the first number in the hours: ex.   3:40:27
3:58:46
4:14:34
683:51:5
71:54:20
72:22:4
73:19:15
740:36:36
7:14:46 Is there any way around this?

Comment: @John: sort first, *then* convert to strings. Strings are always sorted lexicographically.

Comment: @Martijn Doh! Why did I never know about divmod() before? I've been using python for probably 8 years, and I don't remember ever seeing it. I should start following your answers here.

Comment: if `td` is non-negative: `minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 60); hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60); hours += d.days*24` and you could use `td.microseconds` to round to the nearest second.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that was the previous revision :-P I used `td.total_seconds()` to not have to add the `td.days` parameter separately. If `td` is negative, perhaps use `abs(td)` here and prepend a `-`.

Comment: I understand. I prefer integer calculations instead of floats if possible. Floating point computations are not intuitive and may have surprising failure mode.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that's why I floor the `total_seconds()` float; `timedelta.max.total_seconds()` may be too large a float to support microseconds properly (`(timedelta.max - timedelta(microseconds=1)).total_seconds() == timedelta.max.total_seconds()`) but that doesn't matter for the way I use it here; `(timedelta.max - timedelta(seconds=1)).total_seconds()` still works correctly. The `microseconds` portion is handled separately.

Comment: Imagine `microseconds==0`, is it possible `int(f)==(round(f)-1)` where `f=td.total_seconds()`? Note: [`total_seconds()` implementation had changed due to floating-point issues at least once already](http://bugs.python.org/issue8644). Integer arithmetics would eliminate this question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: ah, that bug makes for interesting reading; I've switched back to integer arithmetic only, that ensures compatibility with releases that a) were released before that bug was fixed and b) releases without `timedelta.total_seconds()` (e.g. 2.6).

Answer (score 0):

If you are ignoring the days in the count, you can convert the timedelta directly.

```py
def timedelta_to_time(initial_time: timedelta) -> time:
    hour = initial_time.seconds//3600
    minute = (initial_time.seconds//60) % 60
    second = initial_time.seconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60)

    return str(datetime.strptime(
        f"{hour}:{minute}:{second}", "%H:%M:%S"
    ).time())
```

Example:

```py
timedelta_to_time(timedelta(days=2, hours=10, minutes=20, seconds=3))
>> '10:20:03'
```

```py
timedelta_to_time(timedelta(hours=10, minutes=20, seconds=3))
>> '10:20:03'
```