# Add two hours python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I need to add two timedeltas in hours. For the moment I do this:

```
t_day = timedelta(hours=self.time_day_hours,
                  minutes=self.time_day_minutes)

t_night = timedelta(hours=self.time_night_hours,
                    minutes=self.time_night_minutes)

total = str(t_day + t_night)[:-3]
```

It only works if the total time is under one day. If it's higher, it starts a new day. And I don't want this. For exemple, I want :

```
7h56m + 21h05m = 29h01m
```

How do I add up timedeltas and get total hours?

Comment: What do you mean *"two hours"*? Times?

Comment: Yup, you right sorry, I mean *two times* (this how we say it in french).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use division for this sort of stuff:

```
>>> hours_23 = datetime.timedelta(hours=23)
>>> hours_2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
>>> hours_25 = hours_23 + hours_2

>>> hours_25 / datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
25.0
```

Or, if you prefer, the [`total_seconds()` method](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
>>> hours_25.total_seconds() / (60 * 60)
25.0
```

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Uh, wait, it doesn't work perfectly.. I tried to add 22h39 to 13h34 and it gave me   `36.21` but I should have `36.13`.

Comment: @Wizix: `36.21` is the total number of hours (which I thought it was what you were asking for). `36.13` is `hours.minutes`, which is a totally different thing. Look at the [duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503838/how-can-i-display-timedelta-in-hoursminsec) to find the solution to your problem.